# CanvasJS React - How to make a pie chart slice highlight (aka explode) while at the same time handling the click event

Tags: reactjs, canvasjs

I'm working in React and using this pie chart from canvasjs:
https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-pie-chart/

The chart has an optional 'click' function for handling events. Here is the documentation for that.
https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/click/

The problem is when I implement 'click', and call a function to update my label (in a parent component) it changes the default behavior and no longer expands the slice.

I've tried lots of different things to fix it, but it seems I cannot get around the problem.

This code works to update the label in the parent - notice the line 'click: this.props.onSliceSelected'. I can then get the slice label from the event and update my label.

But as mentioned, the slice no longer expands when I do this.

```
data: [{
                type: "pie",
                animationEnabled: true,
                startAngle: 75,
                toolTipContent: "Select: <b>{label}</b> - {y}% of Total",
                showInLegend: false,
                legendText: "{label}",
                indexLabelFontSize: 16,
                indexLabelFontColor: "white",
                indexLabel: "{label}",
                click: this.props.onSliceSelected,
                dataPoints: sortedData,
                

            }]
```

I have tried to many other things to ensure the slice is getting selected - most involved trying to set exploded = true on the datapoint.

I cannot find a working example of how to do this anywhere.

Appreciate any ideas.

EDIT - Here is a screen shot, I need to update 'selected task' (outside of the chart and in the parent component). Right now the label will update, but the chart will not expand!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update label in pie chart on clicking each slice, you can update `dataPoints[index].label` in [chart-options](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/) and call `chart.render()`. Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-react-pie-chart-updating-indexlabel-onclick) for the same.

Comment: Thank you, but I still have the same problem. I need to update an external label (it is in the parent component, not part of the pie chart). When I use your code exactly, but replace this line: ````this.chart.options.data[e.dataSeriesIndex].dataPoints[
      e.dataPointIndex
    ].label = "New Label";```` with my line ```this.context.onSliceSelected(e)``` -- My label in the parent changes correctly, but the slice still does not expand. Any idea?

Comment: I updated the question to include a screenshot.

Comment: I've recreated the issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-react-pie-chart-exploded-h436d3?file=child.js

Comment: Check updated code here: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-react-pie-chart-exploded-nxozzt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-react-pie-chart-exploded-nxozzt)